# Juicy Pixels complains about not having enough memory

Tags: image, haskell, memory, ghc, ghci

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 7.10.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> import Codec.Picture
Prelude Codec.Picture> Right pic <- readImage "smiley.bmp"
<interactive>: out of memory (requested 4296015872 bytes)
```

`smiley.bmp` is under 300 bytes. Why did I run out of memory?

Comment: What's in the `smiley.bmp` file? Perhaps it claims a huge height and width?

Comment: @Cirdec It is only 9 by 9 pixels. You can click the link above if you want to examine it.

Comment: That's a really good question.  I don't care so much about the actual issue, but just the completeness, hyperlinks, and all.  Very impressive.  Also, have you tried DevIL?

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson Putting links in the code block is actually quite difficult. I was going to raise an issue on meta about it.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson The reason I choose Juicy Pixels is because of gloss compatibility. I will look at DevIL though.

Comment: @PyRulez Notice that [DevIL can convert to Friday](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/friday-devil) and [Friday can convert to JuicyPixels](https://github.com/TomMD/friday-juicypixels) and that can [convert to Gloss](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gloss-juicy), so its very nearly the same format through and through.  After my patches are accepted it will all be O(1) too.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson That is insane. Someone should put them all in one library before my head explodes.

Comment: @PyRulez Go for it!  We can have all A-B packages, Devil-gloss is just one more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not really a valid bitmap file and JuicyPixels is not error checking the inputs like it should.  Notice the dimensions...

```
% file smiley.bmp
smiley.bmp: PC bitmap, Windows 3.x format, 8 x -8 x 24
```

Comment: What the? Bad smiley!

Comment: Yeah that was it. It works with another image just fine.

Comment: The bitmap is valid. According to MSDN a negative height means the origin is in the upper left corner.

Comment: Then someone should patch both JP and `file`.

Answer (score 5):

This is a bug in juicypixels where bitmaps with negative heights aren't interpreted properly.

The negative height should denote the origin is in the top left rather than bottom left corner.

I have opened a new bug report here: https://github.com/Twinside/Juicy.Pixels/issues/105

Juicy pixels does not support bitmap particularly well. There are a number of other limitations. (see https://github.com/Twinside/Juicy.Pixels/issues/96)

Comment: Its been fixed now. They even made smiley a test case.